# Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a VB.net program that I got from someone else.  It is comprised of a main form and 6 other modules (all .vb files).  These files all have a "VB" icon next to them in the Explorer pane.  I am trying to make a call to a sub-routine in one of the modules from the main form.  My line of code is:

```
QuoteMgr.StartGettingQuotesLevel2(sSym)
```

where QuoteMgr is the name of the module and StartGettingQuotesLevel2(sSym) is the name of the sub-routine.  When I enter this, I get the error message:

```
Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference.
```

The sub-routine is defined in the QuoteMgr Module as follows:

```
 Public Sub StartGettingQuotesLevel2(ByVal oSymbol As String)
```

What is strange is when I enter:

```
QuoteMgr.
```

(the name of the module with a period), it does not show me all the sub-routines and functions in the module.  It only shows:

```
Update_Level1
Update_Level12
Update_Level2
```

These are Public Const in the module.

Can you tell me what I need to do?

Comment: `QuoteMgr` sounds like it is a class (not a module) and needs to have an instance created.  Open the file and look at it.

Answer (score 3):

What the compiler is trying to tell you with this error message

> Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference

is that the `StartGettingQuotesLevel2` subroutine is an ***instance method*** not a ***shared*** or class method, see a more detailed explanation [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/shared-vbnet)

To call an instance method, you need to have an **object instance** to call it on. In your case, an object instance of the **class type** `QuoteMgr`. Like in the example below:

```
' create a new QuoteMgr object instance
Dim myQuoteMgr As QuoteMgr = New QuoteMgr()

' call its instance method with "abc" as its oSymbol argument.
myQuoteMgr.StartGettingQuotesLevel2("abc")
```

It is possible that you only want a single `QuoteMgr` object instance to be created and used by your main form. In that case, you can make it a **member variable** of your main form and create it once.

```
Public Partial Class MainForm

    ' Create it as a private member variable of the main form
    Private m_QuoteMgr As QuoteMgr = New QuoteMgr()

    ' Use it when "some" button is pressed
    Private Sub btnSome_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSome.Click
        m_QuoteMgr.StartGettingQuotesLevel2(txtSymbol.Text)
        ' And possibly do something with the results.
    End Sub        

End Class
```

Also, if instances of your `QuoteMgr` class depend on other object instances for their tasks, you will have to supply these to the **constructor** method of the `QuoteMgr` class as the **arguments** for its constructor's **method parameters**. Constructors (`Sub New(...)`) look like this:

```
Public Class QuoteMgr

    ' This is a constructor that takes two arguments
    ' - oMainSymbol: a string value
    ' - oKernel: an instance of the type Kernel
    Public Sub New(oMainSymbol As String, ByRef oKernel As Kernel)

        ' ....

    End Sub

End Class
```

That means, that when you create a `QuoteMgr` instance, you have to call its constructor method with the things it need, for example

```
' There must be an instance of Kernel created somewhere. 
Dim myKernel As Kernel = ....

' create a new QuoteMgr object instance with these arguments:
' - oMainSymbol = "SYMABC"
' - oKernel = myKernel
Dim myQuoteMgr As QuoteMgr = New QuoteMgr("SYMABC", myKernel)
```

**Some other recommendations**

- The explanations I have provided, are about basic VB.NET language features (e.g. the terms highlighted in bold). I suggest that before you make any changes to the code you have, you (1) make a backup of it, and (2) try to read a tutorial and practice on something smaller.
- The compiler is (virtually) always right. When it gives you an error message, read it carefully, it will indicate the line where something is wrong and a message that tells you what it needs or is missing.
- It is not the purpose of Stack Overflow to provide tutorials or code. It is a Q&A site where the best questions and answers deal with specific, delineated programming problems, for which succinct answers are possible.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried entering "Dim myQuoteMgr As QuoteMgr = New QuoteMgr()" but received the error message:  Argument not specified for parameter 'oKernel' of 'Public Sub New(oMainSymbol As String, ByRef oKernel As Kernel)'.

Comment: @AliceMeade - That means that you need to pass appropriate values for `oMainSymbol` and `oKernel`.

Comment: @AliceMeade I added some additional explanations and more general recommendations. For this question, that is all I can do.

Answer (score 0):

Right click your application and go to Properties.
Make sure your application type is "Windows Forms Application".

Answer (score -1):

It means that the routine you are trying to call needs to reference an instance of the form to access the routine. You can either reference an instance as Alex says, or you can make the routine 'Shared', so it doesn't need an instance. To do this, change the definition in QuoteMgr.vb to

```
Friend Shared Sub StartGettingQuotesLevel2(ByVal oSymbol As String)
```

Switching it to `Shared' may start showing compiler errors, if the routine accesses form controls or module-level variables. These will need to be added to the parameter list.

Comment: This article may also help: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx

Comment: This is a sub-routine and not a function so I entered Friend Sub StartGettingQuotesLevel2.  But the error still persists over in the main form with the line: QuoteMgr.StartGettingQuotesLevel2(sSym)

Comment: Thanks for the reference.  It looks like "Public" should make it available to anyone.

Comment: Apologies, I misread your original post. If the routine is inside a `Form` (or `Class`) then you will need an instance of the form. Or declare the routine `Friend Shared` (or `Public Shared`).
You may need to rework the routine if it depends on controls in the containing form.