# Can't reference sub-routines in other modules of VB.net program

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I have a VB.net program that I received from someone else.  I am trying to make modifications to it.  The program consists of one main form and 6 classes (all .vb files).

In the main form, I want to call a sub-routine in one of the other modules.  What is strange is that if I enter the name of the module followed by a ".", i.e.

```
QuoteMgr.
```

I don't see the names of the sub-routines in the module.  I only see the Public Const's that are defined.

The sub-routine that I want to call is in a section labelled:

```
#Region "Methods"
```

What do I need to do to be able to call one of these methods?

Comment: How are the `Sub`s declared? Are they `Shared` and/or `Private`?

Comment: They are "Public" subs

Comment: #region tags are just for organizational purposes in Visual Studio and don't affect what you can and can't do, in a coded sense.

Comment: What sort of error does it give you if you key in the method you want to call (whether Intellisense lets you finish it or not?)

Comment: If the Sub is in a `Module` rather than a `Class`, you don't need to use the module name when you call the Sub, so you should be able to remove the `QuoteMgr.` unless you also have `Namespace QoteMgr` at the start of the Module.

Comment: Just updated the description.  These are 6 classes and not modules.  If I try to reference a method in one of the classes I get the error: Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference.

Comment: Thanks.  How do I create an instance of the class?  The class name is QuoteMgr.

Comment: See Alex' answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30338944/1070452) AndAlso [Object's and Classes in VB](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/527aztek.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The confusion was because of the wording you used in your original question before you edited it to say "class" instead of "module".

The two terms in VB.net mean entirely different things.  A class typically must be insantiated as an object to invoke its methods.

So what you need to do is:

```
dim qt as new QuoteMgr
qt.Method("foo");
```

In this case you're creating an instance of QuoteMgr called qt and then invoking its methods.  Alternatively you could modify the QuoteMgr class and set the method you're trying to call to "Shared" and then call it by simply going "QuoteMgr.Method" as you were trying before.

A module is more like a free-standing library of methods that can be called by anything in the same project (by default).

Comment: Thanks.  I put this in but got the following error message for "qt":  Argument not specified for parameter 'oKernel' of 'Public Sub New(oMainSymbol As String, ByRef oKernel As Kernel)'

Comment: @AliceMeade: When you create a QuoteMgr object using `Dim qt As New QuoteMgr` you are calling a Sub in the QuoteMgr class that is called `New`. It looks like in your case, that Sub requires two parameters, one of type String and one of type Kernel. What values you need for those parameters will depend on how your application works.