# Error trying to reference sub-routines in other modules of VB.net program

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I have a VB.net program that I received from someone else. I am trying to make modifications to it. The program consists of one main form and 6 classes (all .vb files).

In the main form, I want to call a sub-routine in one of the other Classes.  I learned from my earlier post, that I needed to create an instance of the class in order to call the method.  I did this using:

```
dim qt as new QuoteMgr
qt.Method("foo");
```

When I enter this, I get the error:

```
Argument not specified for parameter 'oKernel' 
of 'Public Sub New(oMainSymbol As String, ByRef 
oKernel As Kernel)'
```

I think this is because in the Class there is a Sub-routine called "New" that looks like this:

```
Public Sub New(ByVal oMainSymbol As String, ByRef oKernel As Kernel)

    _Kernel = oKernel

End Sub
```

How can I instantiate a new Instance of the class QuoteMgr without running up against this "New" sub-routine?

Comment: You cant.  `Sub New` is the constructor. It is called when you create a *new* instance as in `dim qt as New QuoteMgr`.  The message is telling you that to create a new one you must supply a `MainSymbol` string and a `kernel` object (whatever that is):  `dim qt as New QuoteMgr(sym, krnl)`

Comment: Thanks.  I wonder if I could get rid of this "New" sub-routine.

Comment: probably not.  the class probably requires those things for it to do anything of value.  so the person who wrote it decided they must be specified when the object is created.

Comment: Alice, this appears to be a continuation of your question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30338944/reference-to-a-non-shared-member-requires-an-object-reference-in-vb-net. I added an explanation for this specific issue, as well as some advice to get a tutorial and learn about basic language features such as "constructor", "argument", "instance", "parameter", "member variable", ... Getting rid of this "New" routine is unlikely to help you, because the `QuoteMgr`  will almost certainly depend on the presence of valid instances for `Kernel` and `oMainSymbol`.

Comment: Thanks.  Do you have any idea what Kernel could be?

Comment: it is almost certainly another class which will be in Object Browser and/or have a class in the Solution Explorer

Comment: @AliceMeade: Kernel will be something, probably a class, that is defined somewhere in the application you have downloaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to create a parameterless constructor for the class.